# Play against your own RL-trained AI from gym retro

Tags: reinforcement-learning

so far I have seen people implementing reinforcement learning to build an AI to play and complete games on gym retro, such as street fighter, racing games and so on. However, I was wondering if it is possible to play against your own trained AI to get some sort of human evaluation? Anyone has any idea for this? Thank you

Comment: Most of the games on Gym are one player. If this is specifically about gym retro, then identifying a game you want to do with this, and any progress/ideas you have so far would help narrow things down. Clearly in general it's possible to play a game against an AI, so it would help to know a little more about your setup and your plans

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why the post is downvoted.

1. I understand that you can use gym-retro to build a reinforcement learning agent to play some particular game, lets say street fighter.
2. What I want to know is, is it possible to fight against that agent that you have trained, rather than watching a mere trailer (render) of that agent fighting against the CPU bot in that game. If it is possible, then how should I go about doing it, assuming I have a trained rl agent for street fighter. Any resources out there that can guide this, since the python gym-retro does not have too much details on deployment of trained agents vs humans

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The new details are helpful. However, you have posted them as an answer to your question. Please edit the question instead and put the new details in there.